# How do I turn off the sound of Zoom on Android? (not the mic)

Tags: volume-control, volume, zoom-cloud-meetings

I'm joining a Zoom call on my laptop, but I also want to join the same call on my Android device in order to share my Android device's screen and to use my Android device's camera. I don't want to hear other people's voices coming from both my laptop and my phone, I only want to hear their voices coming from my laptop. So I need to turn off the volume on my Android phone.

If I press the Volume down button, Zoom won't let me decrease the volume all the way to zero. I expected they developed the app this way to help users who don't realise that the volume on their device is set to zero. However, in my use-case, this is proving annoying, as I'm now hearing the same voices coming from my phone and from my laptop.

**How do I turn off sound on an Android device when on a Zoom call?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're joining a meeting, you can find an option "Call via Device Audio" under the button menu "Join Audio".  If you don't enable it, you can't hear the participants' voice.

[image]

Or You may disconnect the audio from the **more** options present at the right- bottom (the dots)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found for this so far is to plug in some headphones into the phone, without wearing the headphones. That way, I don't hear the sound output by the Zoom app on the phone.